# MIDL tab in VS6

Tags: visual-studio, midl

I'm assigned to build a visual studio 6 C++ project (I'm aware this is a problem in itself...). I added an IDL file to the project, but the MIDL tab is not showing for the project or for the file itself. How to make the MIDL tab appear?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually the solution was to copy an existing (another) project with an IDL file and change it's properties/files. This works.